# Does ESP32 support WiFi Direct?

Tags: wifi, esp32, wifi-direct, arduino-esp32, wifip2p

I want to use the wifi-direct feature on ESP32. I want to send data from ESP32 to my Android device using wifi-direct.

However, I couldn't find definite information or existing examples regarding whether ESP32 supports wifi-direct. Can you help?

Comment: The terminology makes this difficult to describe. "Wifi-direct" itself is some existing specs and a certification program. The ESP32 is not a "certified" Wifi-direct device. However all wifi-direct technically does is have one device open a sofware access point and another device connects to it with i.e. WPS. This means even "classic" wifi devices should be able to connecto "Wifi-Direct" devices. 
A specific example of an ESP using a WPS SoftAP is here: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/wifi/wps_softap_registrar . But being the softAP is only one option.

Comment: that said, there doesn't seem to be an example of the p2p discovery part of wifi-direct for the esp32. There are some examples for "Wi-Fi Aware" which might cover some use-cases https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_nan.html